# UITableView Troubles

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

I have created 3 tableview controllers from scratch on the main stroyboard in Xcode. I have desgined the rows etc.

Now when I create files, File-New to create the .h and .m files (Subclass UITableViewController), then I add the file as the Custom Class in the UITableView , the tableview does not show.

If I set the Custom Class as blank (default UITableViewController) it works fine.

Any ideas why it is blank and only the NAV bar is shown when I add the custom class to the table view controller.

thanks 
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think screenshots of where you are putting what would be a good deal of help.

Comment: And some code would help too.

Comment: well when you link the .h and .m file with the TableView controller, you get boilerplate code. So without any .h and .m file linked to the TableView controller it shows the tableview design on my iphone but with it, you only get the nav bar and no tableivew design.. I will see if i can get a screen shot..

Comment: Make sure to remove all the boilerplate code in your .m file.